# calling a boolean method inside the condition block of if statement?

Tags: c++, if-statement, boolean

I am defining a function of a template class that uses a list class.

I defined erase function in this list class, which returns true if erase succeeds and false if erase fails, and all I have to do here is just to call this function.

However, I need to count the size of the list, n, and I want to decrement it only if list.erase(itr.list_iter) call returns true.

More succinctly, will the following lines of code call list.erase(itr.list_iter) function and decrement n and call refresh() only if it succeeds? Or does it not actually erase the element in the list?

```
void erase(iterator itr) {
    if(list.erase(itr.list_iter)) {
        --n;
        refresh();
    }
}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten the `[python]` tag (and `[c#]` for good measure).

Comment: which language is it?

Comment: Seems to be C++ ("template class")

Comment: It's a bit hard to follow, but are you just asking whether the conditional expression in an `if` statement gets executed? How could it not be?

Comment: Irrespective of which language being used, any container's size should be a queryable attribute belonging to the container. Having to maintain it deliberately doesn't sound like a good design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. It will always be called. It is equivalent to:

```
{
  bool res = foo();
  if(res)
  {
    do_stuff();
  }
}
```

You even can declare variable inside if:

```
if(int res = int_foo())
{
  do_smth(res);
}
else // res == 0
{
  do_smth_else();
}
```

That is written in every book =)